# Функция PtInRect в Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли функция

```
function PtInRect ( const TheRectangle : TRect; const ThePoint : TPoint ) : Boolean;
```

в Лазарусе? И если есть, то какой модуль подключать.

Answer (score 2):

да, должно быть в модуле types. Если же нет, просто напишите её.

```
function PtInRect(const Rect : TRect;const p : TPoint) : Boolean;
begin
   PtInRect:=(p.y>=Rect.Top) and
        (p.y<Rect.Bottom) and
        (p.x>=Rect.Left) and
        (p.x<Rect.Right);
end;
```

Но вот о параметрах c The в названии - первый раз слышу:).